# how to read groovy model in gsp as object notation.

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm working with a grails project that has a model been passed to the gsp page. I can easily run through all the properties of the model and populate my fields in the gsp.
I need to be able to store each item of the model in a data attribute to later use in my JS file. 
The problem is knowing how to store it as an object so I can use it later in my JS.
First here is my html where I'm looping through all the items in the model.

**.gsp file**

```
<g:each var="item" in="${modelData}">
    <option value="${item.sequence}" data-user="${item.properties}"/>${item.name}</option>
</g:each>
```

item returns the below structure.

```
com.me.data.model.MyData(my name, 00345)
com.me.data.model.MyData(your name, 00155)
com.me.data.model.MyData(his name, 00678)
```

If I run item.properties I get

```
{name=my name, sequence=00345}
{name=your name, sequence=00155}
{name=his name, sequence=00678}
```

The problem is getting it so it's stored in the data-user attribute like an object

```
{name:my name, sequence:00345}
{name:your name, sequence:00155}
{name:his name, sequence:00678}
```

I'm new to grails so not exactly a groovy expert. I also didn't write the code in the controller or model so I'm not sure if passing a model to the gsp is best practice or passing it JSON is better. 
I was told by the person who wrote the controller that it was stupid to pass JSON when they could just pass the model to the view. Which I was a little skeptical of. But wanted to see what if any are best practice in this situation.

Is there any way for me to convert this model to correct notation to store in my data attribute for later use in JS.

Comment: You can use `${new grails.converters.JSON(item).toString(false).encodeAsHTML()}` though it will include some extra properties (id, class) that you may not want unless you tweak it (register your own data marshaller for example).

Comment: If you need to do this often I suggest writing a nice taglib :) Only mentioning this because you wrote you're new to Grails, but it's very easy to do and it will make GSPs shorter and cleaner.